How to make a lazy loaded list in SwiftData?
I would guess that SwiftData supports lazy loading of a simple list, but according to Instruments this simple code example is not lazy loaded. All 4200 posts are fetched when the view appears.
How do I make the list lazy loaded?
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct testappApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Post.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var posts: [Post]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(posts) { post in
                Text(post.title)
            }
        }
        // Uncomment for initial posts creation
//        .onAppear {
//            for i in 0..<4200 {
//                let post = Post(title: "Post \(i)")
//                modelContext.insert(post)
//            }
//        }
    }
}

@Model
final class Post {
    var title: String
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}



Let’s make one thing clear, the query fetches all 4200 objects because that’s what you have told it to do with your code. There is no such thing as lazy loading within SwiftData, List has it but certainly not Query.

Thanks for that clarification. Now, do you have any suggestions on how to make the query lazy loaded? I see that SwiftData supports fetchLimit, but I am not sure what the best approach is when used in combination with a list.

Note that there is also a fetchOffset property so with the two you could have some sort of pagination but I haven’t tried that myself so I don’t have any further advice to offer

You can use the propertiesToFetch property of FetchDescriptor and set it to \Post.title so it is fetched at the same time as all of the row IDs, that way it won't load in all the data of the entire object. It will load that when any other property is accessed.
That sharedModelContainer should be moved outside of the App struct. Swift doesn't have lazy vars in structs. So your model is being init at App init but it needs to be done in body. If you move it out (make it fileprivate if you like) then it will be lazy.
